# making dimension of an Array flexible

Tags: java

can someon help me to change this code , I tried to make the dimension of Vectorarray flexible, sothat the user can determine the dimension and also how 
many numbers have to be saved in each vector.

I have created here an array of the class and i didn't found yet any example about
converting an array of the class to double .

I attempt ,but the result was ,that this array can't be converted to double.

here is mein Code:

first page:

```
package menu;

public class Vector3d {

    private final float x;
    private final float y;
    private final float z;

    Vector3d(float x, float y, float z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public void Vectorprint() {

        System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")");

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param V1
     * @param V2
     */
    public void addition(Vector3d V1, Vector3d V2) {

        float value1 = V1.x + V2.x;
        float value2 = V1.y + V2.y;
        float value3 = V1.z + V2.z;

        System.out.println("The Vector after addition (" + value1 + "," + value2 + "," + value3 + ")");

    }

    public void Difference(Vector3d V1, Vector3d V2) {

        float value1 = V1.x - V2.x;
        float value2 = V1.y - V2.y;
        float value3 = V1.z - V2.z;

        System.out.println("The Vector after subtraction (" + value1 + "," + value2 + "," + value3 + ")");
    }

    public void dotProduct(Vector3d V1, Vector3d V2) {
        float value1 = V1.x * V2.x;
        float value2 = V1.y * V2.y;
        float value3 = V1.z * V2.z;
        float sum = value1 + value2 + value3;
        System.out.println("The scalarproduct is : (" + value1 + "," + value2 + "," + value3 + ")   the complete Value of Scalarproduct : " + sum);

    }

    public float multiplcation(Vector3d V, int number) { 

        float value1 = V.x * number;
        float value2 = V.y * number;
        float value3 = V.z * number;

        return value1 + value2 + value3;
    }

    public void unitVector(Vector3d v ){
      double longVector = Math.sqrt((v.x*v.x)+(v.y*v.y)+(v.z*v.z));
      double value1=v.x/longVector;
      double value2=v.y/longVector;
      double value3=v.z/longVector;


      System.out.println("the lang of this vector : " +longVector);
      System.out.println("The unitvector is : ("+ value1+","+value2+","+value3+")");
    }
}
```

second page :

```
package menu;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Vector3d v1, v2, v3;
        float element1, element2, element3, element4, element5, element6;

        System.out.println("the elements of first vector :  ");
        element1 = input.nextFloat();
        element2 = input.nextFloat();
        element3 = input.nextFloat();

        v1 = new Vector3d(element1, element2, element3);

        System.out.println("the elements of second vector :  ");
        element4 = input.nextFloat();
        element5 = input.nextFloat();
        element6 = input.nextFloat();

        v2 = new Vector3d(element4, element5, element6);
        v3 = new Vector3d(0, 0, 0);

        System.out.println("the inputed first Vector");
        v1.Vectorprint();

        System.out.println("the inputed second Vector");
        v2.Vectorprint();

        v3.addition(v1, v2);
        v3.Difference(v1, v2);
        v3.dotProduct(v1, v2);

        System.out.println("sellect a number to multiplication with Vector : ");
        int multiplicator = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Which Vector would you like to sellect for first input (V1) and second (V2)");
        String answer = input.next();
        if ("V1".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            System.out.println("The Vector after multiplication : " + v3.multiplcation(v1, multiplicator));
        } else if ("V2".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            System.out.println("The Vector after multiplication : " + v3.multiplcation(v2, multiplicator));
        }

        v3.unitVector(v1);
    }
}
```

here what I mean exactly ,that the array can't be converted to double :

```
package menu1;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter the size of vektor : ");
        int vectorSize=input.nextInt();

        vector1 vectorArray[] =new vector1[vectorSize];
        vector1 object1 =new vector1();
        double convertor =vectorArray[vectorSize];
        for (int i=0;i<vectorArray.length;i++){
          vectorArray[i]=input.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println("the elements of the vector are :"+Arrays.toString(vectorArray));

        vector1 v1, v2, v3;
        float element1, element2, element3, element4, element5, element6;
        System.out.println("the elements of first vector :  ");
        element1 = input.nextFloat();

        element2 = input.nextFloat();

        element3 = input.nextFloat();

        v1 = new vector1(element1, element2, element3);

        System.out.println("the elements of second vector :  ");
        element4 = input.nextFloat();
        element5 = input.nextFloat();
        element6 = input.nextFloat();
        v2 = new vector1(element4, element5, element6);

        v3 = new vector1(0, 0, 0);

        System.out.println("the inputed first Vector");
        v1.Vectorprint();
        System.out.println("the inputed second Vector");
        v2.Vectorprint();
        v3.addition(v1, v2);

        v3.Difference(v1, v2);

        v3.dotProduct(v1, v2);

        System.out.println("sellect a number to multiplication with Vector : ");
        int multiplicator = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Which Vector would you like to sellect for first input (V1) and second (V2)");
        String answer = input.next();
        if ("V1".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            System.out.println("The Vector after multiplication : " + v3.multiplcation(v1, multiplicator));
        } else if ("V2".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            System.out.println("The Vector after multiplication : " + v3.multiplcation(v2, multiplicator));
        }

        v3.unitVector(v1);

    }

}
```

the new code after modifying :

```
package menu1;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vector {

    private final double vector1[];
    private final double vector2[];
    private final double vector3[];



    Vector(double matrix1[], double matrix2[],double matrix3[]) {
        this.vector1 = matrix1;
        this.vector2 = matrix2;
        this.vector3 = matrix3;


    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void VectorInput(double Matrix[]) {

        System.out.println("input the elements of Vector :");
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.length; i++) {
            Matrix[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }

    }

    public void VectorOutput(double Matrix[]) {

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Matrix));

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Matrix1
     * @param Matrix2
     * @param Matrix3
     */
    public void addition(double Matrix1[], double Matrix2[],double Matrix3[]) {
        double Matrix4[] = new double[Matrix1.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix1.length; i++) {
            Matrix4[i] = Matrix1[i] + Matrix2[i]+Matrix3[i];
        }

        System.out.println("The Vector after addition :" + Arrays.toString(Matrix4));

    }

    public void Difference(double Matrix1[], double Matrix2[]) {
        double Matrix3[] = new double[Matrix1.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix1.length; i++) {
            Matrix3[i] = Matrix1[i] - Matrix2[i];
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Matrix3));

    }

    public void ScalarProduct(double Matrix1[], double Matrix2[],double Matrix3[]) {
        double Matrix4[] = new double[Matrix1.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix1.length; i++) {
            Matrix4[i] = Matrix1[i] * Matrix2[i]*Matrix3[i];
        }

        System.out.println("The scalarproduct :" + Arrays.toString(Matrix4));

    }

    public void multiplcation(double Matrix[], int number) {
        double Matrix3[] = new double[Matrix.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.length; i++) {
            Matrix3[i] = Matrix[i] * number;
        }

        System.out.println("The Vector after multiplcation :" + Arrays.toString(Matrix3));

    }


    /* I need help here , because I didn't find the right way to calculate the unitvector 
       and the result was unfortunately  wrong

       */ 
    public void unitVector(double matrix[]) {
        double matrix2[]=new double[matrix.length];
        double longVector = 0;
        double result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            matrix2[i] = Math.sqrt(matrix[i]*matrix[i]);

        //    for (int j = 0; j < matrix2.length; j++) {
                result = matrix[i] / matrix2[i];
            }

      // }

        System.out.println("The long of the Vector :"+ Arrays.toString(matrix2));
        System.out.println("The unitvector is :" + result);

    }

}
```

````
package menu1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("sellect the size of vectors (maximum 6 elements):");

        int vectorSize = input.nextInt();

        if (vectorSize > 6) {
            System.err.println("Error ! , the number of elements is not acceptable ");
            return;
        }

        double Arrayvector1[] = new double[vectorSize];
        double Arrayvector2[] = new double[vectorSize];
        double Arrayvector3[] = new double[vectorSize];

        Vector object = new Vector(Arrayvector1, Arrayvector2, Arrayvector3);

        object.VectorInput(Arrayvector1);

        object.VectorInput(Arrayvector2);
        object.VectorInput(Arrayvector3);

        System.out.println("The elements of first Vector : ");
        object.VectorOutput(Arrayvector1);
        System.out.println("The elements of second Vector : ");
        object.VectorOutput(Arrayvector2);

        System.out.println("The elements of third Vector : ");
        object.VectorOutput(Arrayvector3);
        //  System.out.println("The addition of two Matrix : ");
        object.addition(Arrayvector1, Arrayvector2, Arrayvector3);

        System.out.println("First Vector -  Second vector:");
        object.Difference(Arrayvector1, Arrayvector2);

        System.out.println("Second Vector -  Firstvector:");
        object.Difference(Arrayvector2, Arrayvector1);

        object.ScalarProduct(Arrayvector1, Arrayvector2, Arrayvector3);

        System.out.println("input a number for multiplication with Vector : ");
        int multiplicator = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Which Vector would you like to sellect for first one input (1), second (2) and third(3)");

        String answer = input.next();
        if ("1".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            //   System.out.println("The Vector after multiplication : " );
            object.multiplcation(Arrayvector1, multiplicator);

            object.unitVector(Arrayvector1);
        } else if ("2".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            //    System.out.println("The Vector after multiplication : ");
            object.multiplcation(Arrayvector2, multiplicator);

            object.unitVector(Arrayvector2);

        } else if ("3".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            object.multiplcation(Arrayvector3, multiplicator);
            object.unitVector(Arrayvector3);
        }

    }

}


    ```
````

Comment: If you want a dynamic Array I would just use some sort of `List` for example an `ArrayList`. Other than that it's unclear what you're asking, what's not working exactly?

Comment: What's the problem? I'm not finding this very clear.

Comment: Your question lacks a focused problem statement.  No one should have to dig through all your code to find out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you want to be able to create an array with Vector3d objects as elements. To do that you have to use a collection. There are many types depending on what you want to do. Basically an collection is an object used to store or group multiple items along with ways to use those elements (adding, removing, accessing). For your needs you can use the most common, an ArrayList. This is the default that most programmers start with, and works for most needs.

ArrayList array;

I will not go into detail about how to use it, that is what you need to figure out yourself.

Comment: when I create this list and set the deminsion  how can i make three vectors without using the parametrized constructor.

Comment: @samihtw Have I answered your questions?

Comment: thanks , I know that It i have to use collection , but I didn't find any similar example or tutorial yet , could you send me an example . I found many examples about accessing , addition, multiplication  the elements in static arrays but not in dynamic.

Comment: I don't know how I can  access the elements in dynamic arrays ,especially that will be every time different and it is also depended on user's decision ,then we don't have specific index to determine the elements or numbers ,which can be added with each other.
frankly I did not find  any tutorial about that

Comment: What you are asking, I think, is a trivial task: "I don't know how I can access the elements in dynamic arrays" . Every programmer should know how to do this. It is extremely common, so there has to be thousands of tutorials. The first step is to search.

Comment: If you look at the code after modifying , , you know exactly what i meant . I have done it without using an arrayList as you said . Now i try to find a way to calculate the unitvector using an Array as a parameter in the unitvector Method.